# How is this an un-initialized constant. (Mixins in rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mixins

under `lib/` I have 'aisis_writer/loader.rb' which, inside that file, looks like:

```
module AisisWriter
  module Loader
  end
end
```

I then have, in my `application.rb` the following set up:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module AisisWriter
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Load Lib
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)

    # Use Rack Attack For Throttling
    config.middleware.use Rack::Attack
  end
end
```

From there I did, in the `ApplicationController.rb`: `include AisisWriter::Loader` and then I ran my tests and got:

`'<class:ApplicationController>': uninitialized constant AisisWriter::Loader (NameError)`

Either I cannot do what I am doing because of naming conflicts or I am doing something wrong. Any one care to tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Every Rails developers face this problem at least once in their Rails career. Here is an awesome post which explains rails autoloading. http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your `config.autoload_paths` is broad enough -- it's not including subfiles of the lib directory.

This should do the trick:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('lib', '{**/}')]
```

Comment: Now I get: `Unable to autoload constant Loader, expected /Users/Adam/Dropbox/AisisGit/Aisis-Writer/lib/aisis_writter/loader.rb to define it (LoadError)`

Comment: @user3379926 it looks like you have a typo in your path there. In the error there it is looking at `lib/aisis_writter` with two 't's, but I think you mean to have just 1.

Answer (score -1):

Try defining like this within 'aisis_writer/loader.rb'

```
module AisisWriter::Loader
end
```

Comment: Its a mixin loader, why would I want a class?

Comment: This is because you are loading `loader.rb` file in lib folder. So, when application will run, this file will be called and will search with `class name` same as of `file name` which it is unable to find. You have another option to define Loader Module as `module AisisWriter::Loader`